# How to pass component property to sub component?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have two nested components.

The `main` component is here:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{cat}}!</h1>`
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  cat: string;

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Main component has a property names `cat`. I want to pass it to sub compoent.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sub',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class SubComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() cat: string;

  ngOnInit() {
     console.log(this.cat) // This writes undefined in console.
  }
}
```

And I used it in `app.component.html` as following:

```
<main>
  <sub [cat]="cat"></sub>
</main>
```

But `cat` property in `main` component does not pass in `sub` component.

[Working Code is here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3wzmm)

Comment: Hope this link which i have modified with your code will help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-child-communication-nate-n5ihhk

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally used the wrong templates for your `main` and `sub` component, your `main` component should have the template `<ng-content></ng-content>` and your `sub` component the template `<h1>Hello {{cat}}!</h1>`.

Because if you don't have an `ng-content` node inside your `main` components template, the `sub` component will never be projected / initialized.

Also if you use `[cat]="cat"` it will look for the property cat on your `app.component`, because you're using it in  the context of the `app.component` component.

The content projection doesn't change the context of your property bindings.

Comment: What difference does it make? And what does this have to do with the solution?

Comment: From your code, your `main` component doesn't project any content into its template (missing `ng-content`), therefore your `sub` component will never be initialized.

Answer (score -1):

you need to pass the value like

```
<sub [cat]="cat"></sub>
```

or you need to assign the cat variable in your main.ts file like

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cat = 'cat';
  }
```

Comment: why I need to pass like that?

Comment: @barteloma : because you are doing a property binding and if you are not explicitly telling the property binding that you want to pass the string it will look for cat variable in your main.ts file which is undefined.

Comment: @DhavalPatel, that's not true. He is passing the `@Input` prop properly. It's just that it's not available at the time of initialization of the Child Component.

Comment: @SiddAjmera: yes you are correct but OP got every time undefined because he hasn't initialized that property in the main component

Comment: This example is string but my cat property may be an object. So `<sub [cat]="'cat'"></sub>` may not be work. I set init value bu it still `undefined`.